# SQL Server data modeling for data like bitmask

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, database-design, data-modeling

Assume that I have a table like this:

| Id | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Blue, Green, Yellow |
| 2 | Blue, Green, Red |
| 3 | Blue, Red |

You can image that Color is a json array of string (**16 values of color only, like a bitmask of enum**) or something like that.
Now I want to make a query like:
`select * from table where Color contains 'Green' and/or Color contains 'Blue'` 
I've tried with full text index, it works well with physical table. But to work with a view based on that table, I have to create another full text index for that view (cannot leverage table full text index like primitive type index for int, string...).

Does any one have idea about how to re-modeling and indexing for fast retrieve the data with a sort of above command without creating an additional table and using join.

Every idea is welcome and appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: You shouldn't store multiple values in same column, when you solve it, it becomes easy to query

Comment: If you want to store data like this or do any processing/flitering/searching on json data you should consider if an RDBMS is what you should be using, perhaps a nosql/document database would be better.

Comment: Actually the Color column has 16 values (enumeration of color) and stored as a bitmask of color. I'm looking for some data struct that can leverage the index of SQL Server. Thank @siggemannen and Stu for support.

Comment: The data structure in SQL Server is called a table with rows and columns - storing data that's not atomic in a single column violates the basic 1NF, you should really only do that if you intend to retrieve the entire value and process it outside of the DB in your app

Comment: @Stu got your idea. So may be I should try another approach. Thanks for support me.

Comment: @Stu sorry for mention you again, do you have any suggestion on how I should re-modeling the table? Flatten the table or create an additional table, or something like that.

Comment: If you're going to use a relational database, you're gonna have to create what's known as a many-to-many relationship - which means a table for colors, a table for whatever entity you're using these colors for, and a table to connect the two.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yeah I want to use index on the Color column. Could you suggest an idea on how can I leverage the enumeration and bitmask attribute of the column?

Comment: What is that bitmask attribute you're talking about? I haven't found any documentation of such attribute

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sorry for reply late. For bitmask I mean the Color column has 16 values only (Green, Read, Blue, Yellow, White...) and the users can make query like Color = Red | Green | Blue

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you're referring to something built in SQL Server I'm not aware about. In that case, my previous comment stands: this is a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: That's **not** a bitmask you have described and seems totally misleading, a *bitmask* would be an integer value where each bit represents a property and is set, evaluated or cleared using bitwise operations.

Comment: @Stu I understanding your confusion. I mean each color is a value presented by a bitmask value (Red = 1 << 0, Green = 1 << 1, Blue = 1 << 2 ...). Sorry for not explain thing carefully.